# Amazon Elastic Search Custom Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I´m probably not understanding something here and wanted to ask, if somebody could explain.

I set up an AWS ES domain and created a custom endpoint for it. I provided a ACM certificate which I uploaded upfront and created the domain with it.

Let´s say, the custom endpoint should be a subdomain of my existing ROUTE 53 Domain (eg. logging.my-r53-hosted.domain)
I didn´t do anything at Route 53, yet, just provide an imaginary subdomain as endpoint(example above).

Then what ? .....
When I create this subdomain on Route 53 as CNAME which points to the autocreated endpoint of AWS ES (eg. vpc-logging-72354762589234579.es.amazonaws.com) and curl the custom endpoint (logging.my-r53-hosted.domain) I´m getting just the aws certificate back, but not the one i provided before. That gives me a self signed cert warning. I can circumvent this with --insecure, but that´s obviously not what I want.

Can anybody explain how to do it right ?

Thanks all and again thanks for your patience :-)

Greetings!

Comment: How exactly did you set your SSL certificate on ACM?

Comment: created an own one over my companies ca and imported it together with key and chain into acm

Comment: https://sequencediagram.org/index.html?presentationMode=readOnly#initialData=FAFwliA2CmAECiBlAtAQQMbugZ27A9gG7QBOsAwgK7YgB08AdgCYAOtwAMvgObYAWYFi1LIAfAwDuyGgEN0AawBcJHPkjFY6aiHwBbZNGYt8YBiGSUSkWAApIPbqe61dAT2QkArAGZaTPTKmosCS0iBy8mIAIgByKIikxCSKsCrYahoyTExp2MCx8Yki4lKyCorkMagAsvCwMpBgMtgAOgw2hCzoyPbcjgzI3gBs3p4ALN4ATADsQ2OTnm20MroyAF74DDIS2LToegCUIaXhCmJcvAJCpBVVtfWNzZw8-ILCJGKhZUrYhkywfBAIBYeBUAEdKDgQLYAEpIAAqRy+p0iolQAHUUEgDEYTGZFL9mACgSCPNAIVDYQijhisSg-sZTOYSmEIsocMYGL9bJMAAy8g6wCQQPiabR6WBtVDkaqaUjQmxtSqKXr9ZxuDw+PwBUwAGjaiFQMRVDicLncXl8-lWpjaSJOEXOLyu73Z2E53JsfIFsFofvYwEDQA

Comment: That´s how I expected it to work, roughly :-(

Comment: But that can´t work, because the autogenerated hostname (vpc.......amazonaws.com) would have to be in SAN of the certificate. But that´s not possible, because you first have to generate the cert and and then ES generates the endpoint name ..... so a hen-egg problem. What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a wild card certificate like *.youdomain.com in ACM.

While creating the ES cluster select the custom domain option and add Custom hostname as your subdomain (e.g: elasticsearch.yourdomain.com) And for certificate chose wildcard certificate from ACM.

If you have cogito auth for kibana You will need also need to follow these steps:

1. Go to Cognito pool
2. Under App integration > App client settings
3. Update Sign-in and sign-out URLs according to your subdomain.